# Mod Rewrite not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess

EDIT:

Thanks to Anubhava, Here is the rewrite in the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w_|-]+)$ main.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What it does:
It takes mysite.com/tatata and sends it to main.php?u=tatata

That works just fine.
However, when I try to do mysite.com/cc it gives me 403 forbidden errors. I tried to see if there was some hidden .cc folder and no, there is no /cc in my site. I tried, /a and /aa because I thought I had maybe messed up the rewrite to require 3 letters at least. Both those rewrite correctly.

So what can cause this kind of behavior. I am guessing I am missing something with the way rewrites function.

-----Edit more----

So to see what would happen, I added :

```
RewriteRule ^([\w_|-]+)\/$ main.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now it takes /admin/ (an actual directory) and outputs /main.php?u=admin
But with /cc/ or /cc ... still the same problem.

The situation occurs on two machines, set up by two different people.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w_|-]+)$ main.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**In a regex hyphen needs to be first or last in square brackets otherwise it is used for range representation**.

Comment: Noted, but it doesn't fix the /cc problem I have.

Comment: Just comment this whole rule and see what is the behavior. I suspect some external player in this issue.

Comment: If you have any idea on what can cause /cc to not work on 2 different machines, I am opened to all suggestions. I mean, I could easily block that from ever being linked, but what if there are other broken links like that?

Comment: There are lot of things that can go wrong from 1 machine to another. We can investigate only if you provide more info :P Your .htaccess doesn't have any 403 stuff so most likely its some external factor.

Comment: Well on both, it seems like there is a /cc directory. On both I can create, write to, delete a new /cc directory. I just find it very strange that it still acts as if it were there after a delete. I guess I'll just cross my fingers and blacklist /cc from being used :)

Comment: Yes I agree at this time it might be very strange behavior but I'm sure at some point of time you'll find the root cause.